# Query To Read Data From XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, null, xquery-sql

There's already a few similar questions on here, but they don't seem to work for me. I need to query an XML file to extract data from it, so we can use the result of the query for other purposes. I have searched on the net for a method to do this, and it seems the value () method is the recommended method. I tried this with the following code:

```
DECLARE @x XML
SET @x = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BlockOrderMessage xmlns="http://www.test.com/production/block"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/production/block file:/C:/Users/test.xsd"
BlockNumber="BlockNumber1">
<BlockStartTime>01:01:01.001</BlockStartTime>
<ProductionDate>2006-05-04</ProductionDate>
<BlockType>Bloc</BlockType>
<FlightOrders>
    <FlightOrder>
        <Flight>
            <FlightNr>FlightNr0</FlightNr>
            <DepartureDate>2006-05-04</DepartureDate>
            <DepartureTime>01:01:01.001</DepartureTime>
            <AircraftType>AircraftType0</AircraftType>
            <AircraftSeatConfiguration>AircraftSeatConfiguration0</AircraftSeatConfiguration>
        </Flight>
        <CATC>CATC0</CATC>
    </FlightOrder>
    <FlightOrder>
        <Flight>
            <FlightNr>FlightNr1</FlightNr>
            <DepartureDate>2006-05-04</DepartureDate>
            <DepartureTime>01:01:01.001</DepartureTime>
            <AircraftType>AircraftType1</AircraftType>
            <AircraftSeatConfiguration>AircraftSeatConfiguration1</AircraftSeatConfiguration>
        </Flight>
   </FlightOrder>
</FlightOrders>
```

'

```
SELECT @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/Blocktype)[1]','int') AS 'BlockType',
   @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/FlightOrders/FlightOrder/Flight/FlightNr)[1]','VARCHAR (20)') AS 'FlightNr',
   @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/FlightOrders/FlightOrder/Flight/AircraftType)[1]','VARCHAR (20)') AS 'AircraftType'
```

Then i receive a query result of three columns (so far so good), but the records are NULL for all three columns. It does work when I remove the namespace declarations in BlockOrderMessage, so I assume I need to declare these namespaces somewhere in my query, but I cannot find how. Does anyone how I should do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to get data from this XSD or from XML base on this XSD-schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy,
First of all i think it is case sensitive, so correct `Blocktype` to `BlockType`. Do not convert `BlockType` to `int` because it is `string` so use `nvarchar(max)`. Use xml namespaces in your query, like this
`; WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://www.test.com/production/block')`

SELECT @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/`BlockType`)[1]',`'varchar(max)'`) AS 'BlockType',
   @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/FlightOrders/FlightOrder/Flight/FlightNr)[1]','VARCHAR (20)') AS 'FlightNr',
   @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/FlightOrders/FlightOrder/Flight/AircraftType)[1]','VARCHAR (20)') AS 'AircraftType'  `

Here is the full query

```
DECLARE @x XML
SET @x = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BlockOrderMessage xmlns="http://www.test.com/production/block"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/production/block file:/C:/Users/test.xsd"
BlockNumber="BlockNumber1">
<BlockStartTime>01:01:01.001</BlockStartTime>
<ProductionDate>2006-05-04</ProductionDate>
<BlockType>Bloc</BlockType>
<FlightOrders>
    <FlightOrder>
        <Flight>
            <FlightNr>FlightNr0</FlightNr>
            <DepartureDate>2006-05-04</DepartureDate>
            <DepartureTime>01:01:01.001</DepartureTime>
            <AircraftType>AircraftType0</AircraftType>
            <AircraftSeatConfiguration>AircraftSeatConfiguration0</AircraftSeatConfiguration>
        </Flight>
        <CATC>CATC0</CATC>
    </FlightOrder>
    <FlightOrder>
        <Flight>
            <FlightNr>FlightNr1</FlightNr>
            <DepartureDate>2006-05-04</DepartureDate>
            <DepartureTime>01:01:01.001</DepartureTime>
            <AircraftType>AircraftType1</AircraftType>
            <AircraftSeatConfiguration>AircraftSeatConfiguration1</AircraftSeatConfiguration>
        </Flight>
   </FlightOrder>
</FlightOrders>
</BlockOrderMessage>'
; WITH XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://www.test.com/production/block')

SELECT @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/BlockType)[1]','varchar(50)') AS 'BlockType',
   @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/FlightOrders/FlightOrder/Flight/FlightNr)[1]','VARCHAR (20)') AS 'FlightNr',
   @x.value('(/BlockOrderMessage/FlightOrders/FlightOrder/Flight/AircraftType)[1]','VARCHAR (20)') AS 'AircraftType'
```